# Tips for solving linear equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there an easier way to solve linear equations than trial and error?

$$2(3b -1) - (4b -6) = 3$$

Comment: Yes. Solving linear equations is a completely solved problem in mathematics - you can do it every time. See Ross's answer.

Comment: To emphasize @JackM 's comment, I would dare to venture that it's the basis for the field of algebra. ("Basis" and "field" are not meant in any algebraic sense in the previous sentence, ironically.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the distributive principle to write $2(3b-1)=6b-2$
Now gather all the terms in $b$ together and put all the terms without $b$ on the right.
 Divide by the coefficient of $b$.

Answer (score 4):

$2(3b-1)-(4b-6)=3$

$6b-2-4b+6=3$

$2b+4=3$

$2b=-1$

$b=-\frac12$

Answer (score 1):

Given the equation:

$$2(3b -1) - (4b -6) = 3$$

We must expand first, note the minus sign is distributed just like the $2$:

$$2(3b -1) - (4b -6) = 3$$
$$6b-2+ (-4b+6) = 3$$
$$6b-2-4b+6 = 3$$

Gathering like terms and solving for $b$:

$$2b=-1$$
$$\boxed{b=\dfrac{-1}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

To solve $2(3b - 1) -(4b -6) =3$ for the unknown $ b $, it is best to simplify the equation's left side. To do that:

1. Distribute: $2(3b - 1) -(4b -6) = (2 \cdot 3b - 2 \cdot 1) - 1 \cdot 4b - 1 \cdot {-6} = 6b - 2 - 4b + 6$

   2. Combine like terms: $ 6b - 2 - 4b + 6 = 6b - 4b - 2 + 6 = 2b + 4 $

Thus, $$ 2(3b - 1) -(4b -6) =3 $$ $$ <=> 2b + 4 = 3$$

Subtract $4$ from each side of the equation:
$$ 2b + 4 - 4 = 3 - 4$$ $$<=>2b = -1$$

Finally divide $2$ to each side to isolate the unknown $b$:
$$\frac{2b}{2} = \frac{-1}{2}$$ $$<=>b = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Thus, $ b = -\frac{1}{2} $.